# Football Field Size

Tags: rules, football

Just the other day I was talking to a colleague and he was telling me soccer fields can differ in size, up to 20 meters in width.

Can somebody give me the exact word on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [IFAB Laws of the Game](http://theifab.com/laws/the-field-of-play/chapters/dimensions), the width of the field can be between 45 to 90 meters and must be smaller then its length.

The full rule:

### Dimensions

> Law 1 – the field of play
>
> The length of the touch line must be greater than the length of the goal line.
>
> Length (touch line):
>
> - minimum 90 m (100 yds)
> - maximum 120 m (130 yds)
>
> Width (goal line):
>
> - minimum 45 m (50 yds)
> - maximum 90 m (100 yds)
>
> All lines must be of the same width, which must be not more than 12 cm
>   (5 ins).

### International matches

For [international matches](http://theifab.com/laws/the-field-of-play/chapters/dimensions-for-international-matches), the following dimensions are needed:

> Length
>
> - minimum 100 m (110 yds)
> - maximum 110 m (120 yds)
>
> Width (goal line):
>
> - minimum 64 m (70 yds)
> - maximum 75 m (80 yds)